# Blackbox or whitebox unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing

Suppose I have code like this:

```
class SomeEntity
{
    // ... some properties and methods here

    public function saveAndChangeState()
    {
        $result = $this->save(); // method for saving object somehow

        $this->changeState(); // changes state of object - e.g., sets some properties e.t.c.

        return $result;
    }

    public function save() { /* ... */ }

    public function changeState() { /* ... */ }
}
```

I can write two kinds of unit tests for this method.

Whitebox:

```
class SomeEntityTest extends TestCase 
{
    public function testSaveAndChangeState()
    {
        $expected = true;

        $SomeEntity = $this->getMock('SomeEntity', [
            // replace only these methods
            'save', 
            'changeState',
        ]);
        $SomeEntity->expects($this->once()) // should be called once
            ->method('save')
            ->willReturn($expected); // stub implementation will return $expected
        $SomeEntity->expects($this->once())
            ->method('changeState');

        $actual = $SomeEntity->saveAndChangeState();    

        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
    }
}
```

And blackbox:

```
class SomeEntityTest extends TestCase 
{
    public function testSaveAndChangeState()
    {
        $SomeEntity = new SomeEntity();

        $result = $SomeEntity->saveAndChangeState();    

        // here come assertions about state - that I can see a persisted object, 
        // some properties of $SomeEntity have changed e.t.c.
    }
}
```

If I choose whitebox:

- `testSaveAndChangeState()` will be shorter
- `testSaveAndChangeState()` won't fail if I change implementation of `changeState()` inappropriately - so my unit test won't alert me that `saveAndChangeState()` works incorrectly

If I choose blackbox:

- `testSaveAndChangeState()` will be much more difficult, because I need to check every part of my app that is touched by `save()` and `changeState()`
- `testSaveAndChangeState()` will alert me about problems with `saveAndChangeState()` if I change implementation of `changeState()` inappropriately
- I will have huge code duplication - because in `testSaveAndChangeState()` I will mostly repeat assertions from tests for `save()` and `changeState()`

My question is - what should I choose?

Answer (score 0):

You should use whitebox, and add tests for save() and changeState().
I used to think that blackbox was the way to go, but these days I use whitebox because when I change the code and the test fails, the test shows me how the method used to work and helps me remember all cases I need to take into account.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to separate your business concerns and test the interactions between objects.

Separate your Domain Object (the Entity) from Domain Interactors (Entity Service), and separate your Domain Interactors from external concerns like Data Persistence (Database).

Then you could black box test against a Mock Object, and ensure that your EntityService would correctly call the Data Persistence layer.

If you keep your code highly-coupled, and combine business logic with retrieval/persistence/validation/other concerns, then it is very hard to test your system, very hard to find bugs and very hard to change.

Sample Unit Test pseudocode

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyEntityService_SaveEntity_DataAccessSaveIsCalled()
{
    var inMemoryDatabase = new FakeDatabase(); 
    var service = new MyEntityService(inMemoryDatabase);
    var sampleEntity = new MyEntity { Name = "sampleObject" };

    service.Add(sampleEntity);

    Assert.IsTrue(inMemoryDatabase.LastSavedEntity == sampleEntity); 
}
```